# rgeos setdiff() providing unexpected result

Tags: r

## rgeos setdiff() problem

I have been using setdiff() from rgeos for many years, but I've found a quirk in redoing my work. What I basically want to do is to overlay a transparent hole over an Akima generated image map.
I find that I need to specify one of the hole vertices slightly larger than the polygon in which the hole is to be cut.
Here is the example script:
library(rgeos)

Changing 'maxy' to 2.1 provides the desired effect.  Why not for 1.9?

```
maxy <- 1.9
maxy <- 2.1
x1 <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
y1 <- c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
xy1 <- cbind(x1, y1)
p1 <- as(xy1, "gpc.poly")
plot(p1, main="p1")

x2 <- c(1.1, 1.5, 1.9, 1.1)
y2 <- c(1.1, maxy, 1.1, 1.1) # NOTE: 'maxy' is here!
xy2 <- cbind(x2, y2)
p2 <- as(xy2, "gpc.poly")
plot(p2, main="p2")

plot(setdiff(p1, p2),
     poly.args = list(col = "grey"),
     main="setdiff(p1, p2)", asp=1)
```

If this cannot be fixed, is there another way to accomplish the same?

Thanks ahead of time.